# how do i clean my data from one sheet into multiple sheets

Tags: vba

I have a sheet full of data that needs to be organized into multiple sheets therefore i am trying to find how I could use vba to search for a certain word in a range from a1:K10000 and copy all of the text underneath that word and paste it into a new worksheet then continue the process for each time it find that word (a loop)

Comment: There are many examples on how to do this on this site as well as other sites, it is a very common question.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me, Teach me to code, or show me where to start site.  Please post any code you tried and explain where it is going wrong.  Please see [mcve] and take the [tour]

Comment: `range.find(string)` is one way to find the first instance of the word. Then you can loop `range.FindNext` to find the next entries. Break your process donw in small steps, look for each step on here (or google), and build your code together. And then when something more specific isn't working, you can ask for help about it.